# How to dismiss UIPickerView in iOS7 when I click the screen

Tags: xcode, ios7, uipickerview, dismiss

I have a question about UIPickerView.

I build the UIPickerView , the picker have popup normal,

but I need dismiss the pickerview when I click the screen.

But When I click the screen , the picker have dismiss, but the backgrouond gray color view(?) still remain.

Like this:
[image]

my part code is here

```
    dataAry = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",@"test3",@"test4",@"test5", nil] ;

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true;
    _myTF.inputView = pickerView;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideThePicker)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    }

    -(IBAction)hideThePicker {

    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 260);
    }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger) row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {



        return dataAry[row];
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:        (NSInteger)component
    {
        return [dataAry count];
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:        (NSInteger)component
    {
        NSLog(@"dataAry selected:%ld", row);
    }
```

Have any one teach me how can I totally dismiss pickerview when I touch the screen?

thank you very much.

my test pickerview totally code in here:
git: https://github.com/dickfala/pickerViewTest.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use -

```
-(IBAction)hideThePicker {
    [_myTF resignFirstResponder];
    pickerView.hidden = YES;
}
```

you can hide the `UIPickerView` just by using its 'hidden' property.

## EDIT-

Check updated answer above, you have to resign the text field responder as well.

Comment: Hi rishi, I original use your code, but it's will remain gray view on the screen(like my upper photo). Do you know why? thanks.

Comment: Thank you ,rishi. (Other question)Have possible change the backgroundcolor about the gray color? thanks.

Comment: @dickfala - why not possible :) You can set the background color like `pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];`, I would suggest you to go through the documentation of UIPickerView to get all relevant details.